# Does independence almost everywhere imply independence?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Let be $X$ and $Y$ two random variables such that, for any event $A$,
$P( X \in A \mid Y) = P(X\in A)$ with probability 1.
Can I conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent ?

Comment: I asked myself this question while reading the proof of Basu's theorem on wikipedia which uses this property (in a hidden way).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can conclude that.

First, by the defining relation of conditional probability $P(X \in A | Y)$, for any Borel set $B$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{Y \in B\}}P(X \in A | Y) dP = P(X \in A, Y \in B). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
Next, the given condition $P(X \in A | Y) = P(X \in A)$ with probability $1$ entails that the left hand side of $\eqref{1}$ reduces to
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{Y \in B\}}P(X \in A | Y) dP = \int_{\{Y \in B\}}P(X \in A)dP = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
$\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ together then give $P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$ for any Borel sets $A$ and $B$, which is the definition of independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: So the trick seems to be that the samples that might not be independent are wrinkles that can be ironed out by looking at only events that are measurable. E.g. when we sample a pairs $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$ and define $Y' = Y \cdot \textbf{1}_{X \notin \mathbb{Q}}$ then $X$ and $Y'$ prime are still independent because the times that $Y' = 0$ due to $X \in \mathbb{Q}$ has zero measure and this becomes eliminated when we compute probabilities of measurable events.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus : that's a nice example! X and Y' aren't obviously independent inuitively, and yet..

Comment: @Pohoua in mathematics we can create these cases that have zero measure. But I wonder whether they make physically sense. Imagine some sort of [Maxwell's demon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_demon) that is observing two iid normal distributed variables and interferes whenever one of them is a rational number. That demon will never see action. Possibly there can be another different example with zero measure that is more intuitive, but I find this a difficult topic to make sense in a direct physical way.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus It's not really my field, but I guess that events with probability 0 don't really have a physical interpretation since they never happen. I can't think of any thought experiment using that...

Comment: @Pohoua I imagine sometimes about the situation that a tire get's a puncture and inflates rather than deflates. It *can* happen, but... this is not an event with almost zero probability,  it is just very incredibly low probability. Then, in addition to that, while not having an idea how 'almost zero events' could be created in physics, I imagine that 'life' (a weird association of different atoms) might be an almost zero probability event. If that would be true, then I wonder what this does to all of the other probabilities around us (and whether something like destiny might exist).